Problem to update employee photo in AD using C#
I have tried to update a employee photo in AD using the code below, but I received an error message said:

System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException: 'A constraint
violation occurred.
00002082: AtrErr: DSID-03151EFE, #1:  0: 00002082: DSID-03151EFE,
problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 160023
(thumbnailPhoto):len 181708

I have checked I can make modification in the photo employees because I am using an external tool to do it with my account. And I have used this approach to modify other fields of the user like email, or telephone number without any problem. I think the problem is between the assignment of the byte value to the field, but I am not sure. Thank you for your cooperation.
public static void UpdatePhoto(System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry objADAM, string username)
        {
            DirectorySearcher query = new DirectorySearcher(objADAM);

            query.PropertiesToLoad.Add("thumbnailPhoto");
            query.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + username + "))";
            SearchResult result = query.FindOne();

            System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry user = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

            System.IO.FileStream inFile = new System.IO.FileStream("employeePhoto.PNG", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] binaryData = new byte[inFile.Length]; // Read image into byte array
            int bytesRead = inFile.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)inFile.Length);
            inFile.Close();
            user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Clear();
            user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Add(binaryData); 

            user.CommitChanges();

        }


What is the size of the picture?

@MichaelRoy 178KB

I found the problem. For change the photo with this method, the limit photo size is 100KB
